# How to normalize dataframe based on a column weight

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have this dataframe, and i want to normalize/standarlize it (columns B,C,D) using column A as weight.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 5 | 1 | 12 |
| 26 | 9 | 0 | 2 |
| 10 | 0 | 4 | 1 |

Is that possible?

Comment: What is desired output for given sample input?

Comment: What is normalization with weights? Add an example please.

Comment: I want BCD columns in [0..1] scale, but based on column A weight (number 1 in column C and D should have different output values in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to divide the the values in columns B, C, and D by the corresponding row value in column A.

To do this with a pandas dataframe called df:

```
print(df)

A   B   C   D
34  5   1   12
26  9   0   2
10  0   4   1

cols = df.columns[1:]
for column in cols:
    df[column] = df[column]/df["A"]

print(df)

A   B           C           D
34  0.147059    0.029412    0.352941
26  0.346154    0.000000    0.076923
10  0.000000    0.400000    0.100000
```

Comment: Thank you, @jros, your code solve it! : )

Comment: @tainaamoraes glad I could help!